# Photoshop scripting with JSX in for loop to change fill color of each layer

Tags: javascript, scripting, jsx, photoshop

So, I am tinkering with changing fill colors of layers in a PSD file using JSX. I ultimately want to loop all layers, turning off visibility for all but one, edit the fill color of that layer, save as PNG, and then repeat for all layers and all colors in JSON file. I'm starting small as this is my first attempt, but if your solution can help preempt my downfalls with other tasks then it would be greatly appreciated. Here is what I have (alert properly prompts, but line 5 receives error 1302: no such element referencing line 5):

```
    var layerNum = app.activeDocument.layers.length
    alert(layerNum);
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<layerNum;i++){
      var currentLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.index(i)
      var myColor = new SolidColor();
      //var RGB = HEXtoRGB(Y);
      myColor.rgb.red = RGB[255];
      myColor.rgb.green = RGB[0];
      myColor.rgb.blue = RGB[0];
      currentLayer.fill.color = myColor;
    }
```

Is this because the collection of layers does not start at 0? Should I start with layers.index(layerNum) and use i-- to move down the collection? Any insight would be helpful. Thanks in advance to this always helpful community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `var currentLayer = app.activeDocument.layers.index(i)`

should be this: `var currentLayer = app.activeDocument.layers[i]`

Layers collections are pretty much the same as arrays, starting from 0, so you did it right

Answer (score 1):

As KienT points out you need to use square brackets for layers.

Also it's useful to create a variable that's the `app.activeDocument`, so you don't have to type that out each time. Looping over the layers backwards (or up) is easy - just remember to take 1 off the layers length. You can adjust also make it ignore the background by making the loop start at 1 instead of 0. You can also adjust the layers visibility from true to false (on and off) as you go.

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

var layerNum = srcDoc.layers.length;
// alert(layerNum);

for (var i = layerNum -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
  var currentLayer = srcDoc.layers[i];
  var myColor = new SolidColor;

  // Select the layers as you go 
  srcDoc.activeLayer = srcDoc.artLayers[i];

  // switch layer visibility to on
  srcDoc.visible = true;

  myColor.rgb.red = 255;
  myColor.rgb.green = 0;
  myColor.rgb.blue = 0;

  app.activeDocument.selection.fill(myColor, ColorBlendMode.NORMAL, 100, false);

}
```